# How to fix Weird Drawable Rendering Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-drawable, application-icon

I am trying to create an icon for my Application but I am facing a strange issue :
Android Studio is rendering in a really strange way the icons :

[image: Test screenshot]

I am using Android Studio 4.0.1 on Ubuntu 20.04

Is there a way to fix the problem (clean cache, ...)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem here :
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/id6mop/linux_users_are_you_experiencing_vectordrawable/

It seems to be related to Linux only...

I had to disable the experimental Layout Rendering Engine in
`File -> Settings -> Experimental`